# remove the hours, minutes and seconds from the day time, Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
taxa_bruta_cdi = pd.read_csv("dados CDI .csv",delimiter=";",encoding='cp1252')

taxa_cdi= pd.DataFrame(taxa_bruta_cdi,columns=["Data","Media"])

taxa_cdi['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(taxa_cdi['Data']).dt.normalize()

taxa_cdi=taxa_cdi.pivot_table(index="Data",values="Media",aggfunc='sum')

taxa_cdi.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', sort_remaining=True, by=None)
```

I want to remove the hours, minutes and seconds from the date. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
taxa_cdi['Data'] = taxa_cdi['Data'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: do you know how to merge the dates into month, adding the values ?

Comment: df.groupby(df[‘Data’].dt.strftime(‘%B’))[‘Media’].sum().sort_values() I think this should do

Comment: unfortunately not, if you could...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524207/how-to-join-days-in-months-and-months-in-year-using-dataframes-in-python my question is there

Comment: taxa_cdi = taxa_cdi.groupby(taxa_cdi[‘Data’].dt.strftime(‘%B’))[‘Media’].sum().sort_values() I’m from mobile now so I cannot help more for today